# What was the point of the powder?

Tags: plot-explanation, paranormal-activity

In Paranormal Activity (2007), what exactly was Micah's game plan with the powder? It would show the footprints of the demon, but they didn't need proof that something was in the house. They already knew something was there.

Comment: They knew something was in the house, but using powder helped them track its movement?

Comment: Well, yes, it would help them track the movements, but what exactly did he think he was going to do after that? He was dead set against the Demonologist coming to the house. He and Katie made a deal, and she said that if the powder idea didn't work she was going to call the Demonologist. How exactly was the powder supposed to help with anything other than tracking the demon's movements? It's not as if Micah could physically fight it.

Comment: I'm not so sure that it has any purpose other than to create a sense of fear in the audience. Seeing the demon-like foot prints was pretty scary. My opinion is that invisible "ghosts" or "poltergeists" are not scary to audiences now (after so many movies, they've grown numb to), so visuals need to be incorporated.